# What windows service state is appropriate if OnStart failed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have Windows service on C#.

In the end of OnStart I set the state to SERVICE_RUNNING.

What would be a would be an appropriate status if OnStart caught an exception?

Also how should I stop service effectively in such an event?

Comment: It is not your job to change the service state, the ServiceBase class already does that.  Do not catch the exception.  So the error is properly logged and the service state automagically goes back from StartPending to Stopped.

Comment: ok. perhaps I am wrong on the `set state` but I have to catch all the exceptions and I need to process them.. *and your second remark isn't correct either*.. if I don't catch the exception, or re-throw, yes - it prints the error in the event log and terminate the service.. but! the termination is not 'correct' because it doesn't call OnStop. It just fall through.. bad advice.

Comment: No, it is correct. `OnStop` is only supposed to be called (ultimately by the service control manager) when you actually "stop" the service, i.e. it transitions from `Running` to `Stopped`, not when the start fails.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the status to Stopped and throw an exception:

```
public override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    . . .
    if(somethingWrong)
        throw new Exception("something wrong");
}
```

Comment: I edited the question.. it wasn't clear. I mean if there is an exception and I don't want to proceed cos it was fatal (DB not available for example).. What throwing an exception would achieve? Would it alert Windows to shutdown it gracefully? Any links I can read on this?